# Finding which coins make up the minimum of a total

Tags: python

Given a coin array `[1, 3, 7, 12]` and a total (29) find the minimum number of coins need to make up the amount (correct answer is 4).

My code below correctly finds the minimum number of coins, but not which coins were used to get that minimum. I tried using a dictionary to do it but I was getting really high numbers.

```
def changeSlow(coinValueList, total, coinDict):
    if total == 0:
        return 0

    res = sys.maxint

    for i in range(len(coinValueList)):
        if coinValueList[i] <= total:
            sub_res = changeSlow(coinValueList, total-coinValueList[i], coinDict)

            if sub_res != sys.maxint and sub_res + 1 < res:
                res = sub_res + 1

        if coinValueList[i] not in coinDict:
            coinDict[coinValueList[i]] = 0
        else:
            coinDict[coinValueList[i]] += 1

    return res

coins = [1, 3, 7, 12]
coinDict = {}
print(changeSlow(coins, 29, coinDict)) >> gives 4 correctly
print(coinDict) >> gives {1: 190992, 3: 190992: 7: 190992, 12:190992}
```

The output I am getting is incorrect and not sure why I am getting it wrong:

```
>> 4
>> {1: 190992, 3: 190992: 7: 190992, 12:190992}
```

Can anybody give me tips on what I am doing wrong? I should mention that I have to implement this solution using some kind of recursion.

Comment: Please clarify what your variables are meant to do in your program so we can better assist you. its not clear. Also you should separate the output from the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

5 actually isn't correct. The correct answer is 4 (12, 7, 7, 3). The reason you were getting huge numbers was because you were using the same dictionary reference throughout the function, thus the same dictionary would get incremented for each recursive call. You wanted each recursive call to use and increment its own dictionary.

As Untitled123 mentioned greedy isn't necessarily correct, because it misses the case where choosing the highest coin isn't necessarily the correct answer (which is the case for this one, since choosing 12 twice instead of choosing 12 once, then 7 twice gets you an answer of 5, instead of 4).

Here is my non-greedy solution:

```
# Not really faster, but it avoids your huge numbers issue
def changeFast(coinValueList, total, numCoins, coinDict):

    # Base Case: we've reached the money total we want
    if total == 0:
        return (numCoins, coinDict)

    bestCoins = -1
    bestDict = {}

    for i in range(len(coinValueList)):

        # You need to pass a copy of the dictionary to the
        # recursive calls. Otherwise each recursive call will
        # update the same dictionary!
        dictCopy = {}
        for coin in coinValueList:
            dictCopy[coin] = coinDict[coin]

        coin = coinValueList[i]

        if coin <= total:

            # Increment the corresponding coin slot in the dictionary
            dictCopy[coin] += 1
            (subCoins, subDict) = changeFast(coinValueList, total - coin, numCoins + 1, dictCopy)

            # Update our best results so far
            if bestCoins == -1 or subCoins < bestCoins:
                bestCoins = subCoins
                bestDict = subDict

    return (bestCoins, bestDict)


coins = [1, 3, 7, 12]

baseDict = {}
for coin in coins:
    baseDict[coin] = 0

print(changeFast(coins, 29, 0, baseDict))
# Returns (4, {1: 0, 3: 1, 7: 2, 12: 1}) as expected
```

Answer (score 1):

This really should be done with DP, but your function name suggests that you recognize this already. For the case of [1,7,11] and making 14 cents, the greedy solution fails, so you cannot use it in general. You can only use the greedy solution in special cases, and the common [1,5,10,25,50,100] is one such case where greedy works.

Below is a very inefficient recursive solution.

```
def changeSlow(coinValueList, total):
  options=[]
  for coin in coinValueList:
    if coin < total:
      res=changeSlow(coinValueList, total-coin)
      if res:
        options.append([coin] + res)
    elif coin==total:
      return [coin]
  if options:
    return sorted(options, key=lambda x: len(x) )[0]
  return []

coins = [1, 3, 7, 12]
result=changeSlow(coins,29)
print result, len(result)
```

Comment: I just ran the question's code for [1,7,11] and 14 and got 2 as an answer, which I think is correct (7 and 7), but you seem adamant that this is not true, could you please explain?

Comment: The greedy solution would yield 11,1,1,1 instead since you are taking the highest amount each time. I think my recursive solution works (and it's been lightly tested), and should yield the right answer for most cases.

Comment: Dynamic Programming :). The insight here is that instead of having this crazy exponential amount of recursive calls, we note that to make N cents, we must use the best solution for making N-c cents, where c is some coin value we have. This is a decent link explaining this: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-7-coin-change/

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with recursion. This is a good way to do it, but I am sure there is better.

```
def changeSlow(coinValueList, total, coinsDict):
    if total == 0:
        return 0
    if total >= max(coinValueList):
        total -= max(coinValueList)
        coinsDict[str(max(coinValueList))] += 1
    else:
        coinValueList.pop()
        return changeSlow(coinValueList, total, coinsDict)
    print(coinsDict)
    return 1 + changeSlow(coinValueList, total, coinsDict)



coins = [1, 3, 7, 12]
coinsDict = {'1': 0, '3': 0, '7': 0, '12': 0}
print(changeSlow(coins, 29, coinsDict))
```

Output of this would be 5 coins:

```
{'3': 0, '7': 0, '1': 0, '12': 1}
{'3': 0, '7': 0, '1': 0, '12': 2}
{'3': 1, '7': 0, '1': 0, '12': 2}
{'3': 1, '7': 0, '1': 1, '12': 2}
{'3': 1, '7': 0, '1': 2, '12': 2}
5
```

Let me know if you need any clarification. Hope this helps.

Comment: The solution is right according to the instructions he has provided. He edited the question to do with recursion after I already put an answer which might help him.

Comment: This has nothing to do with recursion...your code does not produce the correct output in the input case of [1,7,11] and making 14 cents.

Comment: Did you consider changing the variables in the dictionary as well? I am getting following output when I run it. You have to change the numbers in dictionary as well. This problem was very vague and asked for specific input.:
`{'11': 1, '1': 0, '7': 0}`
`{'11': 1, '1': 1, '7': 0}`
`{'11': 1, '1': 2, '7': 0}`
`{'11': 1, '1': 3, '7': 0}`
`4`

Comment: The output should be 2, since you use the 2 7-cent coins. I think it's worth assuming that your solution should work for more than just one sample input..

Comment: I see what you are saying. didn't consider that case.

Comment: @deltashade Thank you !